# Slide effect in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html

Jquery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#imgcart").mouseover(function() {
if ($("#sidebar").is(":hidden")) {
$("#sidebar").slideDown('slow');
} else {
$("#sidebar").hide();
}
});
});
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<img src="images/cart.jpg" width="80px" height="30px" id="imgcart">
<div id="sidebar">
</div></div>
```

this is my jquery and html code. I cant get it working. I think something is missing in my code. can u please guide me through it. it would be greatful.. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

[Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Pf5y/2/) changes the display state only when the mouse enters the image, the `mouseover` will not trigger when the mouse leaves element.

What you might be looking for is hover()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imgcart").hover(function () {
        $("#sidebar").stop(true).slideDown('slow');
    }, function () {
        $("#sidebar").stop(true).hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Pf5y/)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're only handle `mouseover` event, you need to handle the case when you **[mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)** the image as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebar').hide();
    $("#imgcart").mouseover(function () {
        $("#sidebar").slideDown('slow');
    });

    $("#imgcart").mouseout(function () {
        $("#sidebar").hide();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5a6Le/)**

or you can use **[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** which bind two handlers and executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves your image:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebar').hide();
    $("#imgcart").hover(function () {
        $("#sidebar").slideDown('slow');
    }, function () {
        $("#sidebar").hide();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5a6Le/1/)**